# listView removing rows and updating

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listView that is being updated from multiple threads, with the threads status and id being displayed. When a thread has ended the item is removed.

My problem is that the way i use to update my listView is by using the listViews ID (to locate the subitems i wish to update). Now, as listView items start getting removed i run into problems because that ID for a specific thread has changed..

Here is the code i currently use to update and remove:

```
    private void AddToListViewThread(string user, string status, int threadNumber)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                       delegate
                       {
                           listView2.BeginUpdate();
                           this.listView2.Items[threadNumber].SubItems[1].Text = user;
                           this.listView2.Items[threadNumber].SubItems[2].Text = status;
                           listView2.EndUpdate();
                       }
                       ));
    }

    private void RemoveFromListViewThread(int threadNumber)
    {
        Invoke(new 
            MethodInvoker(
                       delegate
                       {
                           listView2.BeginUpdate();
                           this.listView2.Items.RemoveAt(threadNumber);
                           listView2.EndUpdate();
                       }
                       ));
    }
```

I now understand that i cannot use the threadNumber as the item index (as items get removed) is there any other way i could achieve this? maybe by targeting the "user" subitem? and then getting subitems from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tag property of the ListViewItem to store a different index (similar to the SQL autoincrement ).

The Tag property is a field used to store metadata about the item.

A simple binary search would let you find the item to remove in Log(n) time.

Your code would looks like this:

```
private void AddToListViewThread(string user, string status, int threadNumber)
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                   delegate
                   {
                       listView2.BeginUpdate();
                       int i = SearchItem(listView2, threadNumber);
                       if ( i > -1)
                       {
                       this.listView2.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = user;
                       this.listView2.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = status;
                       }
                       listView2.EndUpdate();
                   }
                   ));
}

private void RemoveFromListViewThread(int threadNumber)
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                   delegate
                   {
                       listView2.BeginUpdate();
                       int i = SearchItem(listView2, threadNumber);
                       if ( i > -1)
                       {
                           this.listView2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                       }
                       listView2.EndUpdate();
                   }
                   ));
}

private int SearchItem(ListView list, int id)
{ 
         for (int i  = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++) // I used sequential search but you can implement binary instead
         {
            if (((int)list.Items[i].Tag) == id) return i;
         }
         return -1;
}
```

Comment: Oh nice! How can i select what tag to update in the update function after i have set a tag in the beginning?

Comment: You have 2 possibilities, either you maintain an independent order over the tag indexes. In which case you must tell the thread which item to work on. Or make the tag equals the threadnumber. The first solution maintain a sorted set with all the advantages (binary search), the second will use less code but u need to somehow make sure the thread number are unique or you will have collisions. Or you can have an hybrid solution by maintaining an autoincrement index over the threads :)

Comment: Dont understand how i would target this.listView2.Items[threadNumber].SubItems[1].Text = user; this with the tag instead

Comment: You have no direct way of finding the item. You have to look for it. I would use BinarySearch over the list remaining items since the tag index is incremental.

Comment: Im getting: Error: The type or namespace name 'ListViewDataItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have added using System.Web.UI.WebControls; but cant get it to work

Comment: My bad, use this instead ListViewItemCollection

Comment: Still getting error - Error: The type or namespace name 'ListViewItemCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
(i removed the using System.Web.UI.WebControls; ) Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: What framework are you using? I've based my code on the 4.0. Let's try another thing.

Comment: am using .net 4 in my project properties

Comment: ListViewItemCollection is supposed to be the type of ListView.Items. I'll just pass the entire ListView. No need to overcomplicate it :)

Comment: That works now :) but am getting this: Error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int' .. the error is here somewhere: if (list.Items[i].Tag == id) return i;

Comment: hmm, you need to cast Tag. Sorry I've wrote the code by head. if ((int)list.Items[i].Tag == id). You need to do so every time you use Tag, since Tag is of type Object.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at ListViewItem.Tag to see if it works in your specific scenario. You can store the thread's ID in the item's tag at creation and it won't change if you remove other items in the ListView.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag.aspx

Comment: I have implemented the tag to be my threadNumber, but how would i update based on that in the update method?

Answer (score -1):

Try this -> `this.listView2.Remove(this.listView2.Items.FindByValue(threadNumber));`

Comment: That wouldn't work. Consider a listview with 4 items. Now consider that the third thread ends before the forth. Calling this with the parameter 3 (index starting at 0) would simply throw an OutOfRangeException.

Comment: I have updated the asnwer with FindByValue call which should provide correct behaviour